# No Rule to Make target, Secure Boot

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, fedora, kernel-module

I am attempting to compile my own kernel with module and kernel signing, but I keep encountering an error. My kernel config includes the following module compressions:

My config looks like this:

```
--- config-x86_64   2023-06-08 19:48:47.899950209 +0000
+++ config-x86_64   2023-06-14 17:27:46.539666800 +0000
@@ -3952,21 +3952,20 @@
 # CONFIG_MODULE_ALLOW_BTF_MISMATCH is not set
 # CONFIG_MODULE_ALLOW_MISSING_NAMESPACE_IMPORTS is not set
 # CONFIG_MODULE_COMPRESS_GZIP is not set
-CONFIG_MODULE_COMPRESS_NONE=y
-# CONFIG_MODULE_COMPRESS_XZ is not set
+CONFIG_MODULE_COMPRESS_XZ=y
 # CONFIG_MODULE_COMPRESS_ZSTD is not set
 # CONFIG_MODULE_DEBUG is not set
 # CONFIG_MODULE_FORCE_LOAD is not set
 # CONFIG_MODULE_FORCE_UNLOAD is not set
 CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_ALL=y
-# CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_FORCE is not set
-CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_KEY="certs/signing_key.pem"
+CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_FORCE=y
+CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_KEY="temp/secure_boot/key.pem"
 # CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_KEY_TYPE_ECDSA is not set
 CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_KEY_TYPE_RSA=y
-# CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_SHA1 is not set
-# CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_SHA224 is not set
-# CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_SHA256 is not set
-# CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_SHA384 is not set
+CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_SHA1=n
+CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_SHA224=n
+CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_SHA256=n
+CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_SHA384=n
 CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_SHA512=y
 CONFIG_MODULE_SIG=y
 # CONFIG_MODULE_SRCVERSION_ALL is not set
```

I keep running into the following error:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'temp/secure_boot/key.pem', needed by 'certs/signing_key.x509'.  Stop.
```

I do not understand why this error is occurring, as the compilation works fine when I remove the `CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_KEY` parameter and auto-generate keys instead. Since I must use my own key, what could be causing this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Best help for what you need to provide is in certs/KCONFIG. https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.19.17/source/certs/Kconfig